# I want to create pivot table or cross tab for POSTGRESQL. Any help would be appreciated

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pivot-table

I need to join all the three tables as mentioned below

```
datatype
id     code
1      Q_1
2      Q_2
3      Q_3
4      Q_4
5      Q_5
6      Q_6
7      Q_7
8      Q_8
9      Q_9
10     Q_10
```

```
model   
id        datatype_id     values   model_ex_id
1          10             0.001      1
2          8             0.008       1
3          9              0.1        4
4          1              0.9        3
5          2              0.6        2
```

```
model_ex  
id   fk_id  city
1    1      ny
2    2      ny
3    2      ca
4    1      ca
```

This is the final table should like after doing cross tab or pivot. I tried in many ways using cross tab but nothing working. Thanks for your help

```
Final_table
id fk_id  Q_1 Q_2 Q_3  Q_4 Q_5  Q_6 Q_7 Q_8    Q_9    Q_10  
1   1     n   n   n    n   n     n  n   0.08    n     0.001
2   1     n  0.6  n    n   n     n  n     n     n      n
3   1     0.9  n   n    n   n    n  n     n     n      n
4   1     n   n   n    n    n     n  n     n     0.1     n
5   2     n   n   n    n    n     n  n    0.08    n     0.001
6   2     n   0.6  n    n   n    n  n     n      n      n
7   2     0.9  n   n    n   n    n  n     n     n       n
8   2     n   n   n    n   n     n  n     n     0.1     n
```

```
with data as (
  select me.id,me.fk_id, d.code, m."values"
  from model_ex me
    join model m on me.id = m.model_ex_id
    join datatype d on d.id = m.datatype_id
)
select id, fk_id, 
       max("values") filter (where code = 'Q_1') as q_1,
       max("values") filter (where code = 'Q_2') as q_2,
       max("values") filter (where code = 'Q_3') as q_3,
       max("values") filter (where code = 'Q_4') as q_4,
       max("values") filter (where code = 'Q_5') as q_5,
       max("values") filter (where code = 'Q_6') as q_6,
       max("values") filter (where code = 'Q_7') as q_7,
       max("values") filter (where code = 'Q_8') as q_8,
       max("values") filter (where code = 'Q_9') as q_9,
       max("values") filter (where code = 'Q_10') as q_10
from data       
group by id, fk_id;
I tried the above query but i get the results as


id fk_id  Q_1 Q_2 Q_3  Q_4 Q_5  Q_6 Q_7 Q_8    Q_9    Q_10  
1   1     n   n   n    n   n     n  n   0.08    n     0.001
2   1     n  0.6  n    n   n     n  n     n     n      n
3   1     0.9  n   n    n   n    n  n     n     n      n
4   1     n   n   n    n    n     n  n     n     0.1     n
5   1     n   n   n    n    n     n  n    0.08    n     0.001
6   1     n   0.6  n    n   n    n  n     n      n      n
7   1     0.9  n   n    n   n    n  n     n     n       n
8   1     n   n   n    n   n     n  n     n     0.1     n
```

I HAVE EDITED THE ABOVE QUESTION The second column has the same values INSTEAD OF UNIQUE fk_id

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using filtered aggregation:

```
with data as (
  select me.id, d.code, m."values"
  from model_ex me
    join model m on me.id = m.model_ex_id
    join datatype d on d.id = m.datatype_id
)
select id, 
       max("values") filter (where code = 'Q_1') as q_1,
       max("values") filter (where code = 'Q_2') as q_2,
       max("values") filter (where code = 'Q_3') as q_3,
       max("values") filter (where code = 'Q_4') as q_4,
       max("values") filter (where code = 'Q_5') as q_5,
       max("values") filter (where code = 'Q_6') as q_6,
       max("values") filter (where code = 'Q_7') as q_7,
       max("values") filter (where code = 'Q_8') as q_8,
       max("values") filter (where code = 'Q_9') as q_9,
       max("values") filter (where code = 'Q_10') as q_10
from data       
group by id;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/X0WAgl--?hide=2)

Comment: I have edited above table as I had have to add extra columns. The second column has same values instead of unique values. I tried left join and group by but i could not find the results

Answer (score 0):

Doing so is ridiculously hard.

```
CREATE TABLE datatype(id serial , code text);
INSERT INTO datatype
SELECT  r,format('Q_%s' ,r)
FROM generate_series(1, 10) r;

CREATE TABLE model (id serial , dtid serial , value numeric , exid serial);
INSERT INTO model
SELECT  unnest(ARRAY[1,2 ,3,4 ,5])
       ,unnest(ARRAY[10,8 ,9,1 ,2])
       ,unnest(ARRAY[0.001,0.008,0.1,0.9,0.6])
       ,unnest(ARRAY[1,1 ,4,3 ,2]);

CREATE EXTENSION crosstab;

SELECT  *
FROM crosstab
( $x$
    WITH a AS
    (
        SELECT  exid, dt.id, dt.code ,SUM(value)
        FROM datatype dt
        JOIN model m
        ON m.dtid = dt.id
        GROUP BY 1,2,3
        ORDER BY 1,2
    ) , b AS
    (
        SELECT  exid
        FROM a
        GROUP BY  1
    )
    SELECT  b.exid, dt.code, coalesce(a.sum, 0)
    FROM b
    JOIN datatype dt
    ON true
    LEFT JOIN a
    ON a.exid = b.exid AND a.id = dt.id
    ORDER BY 1, 2$x$
) AS (exid serial , q1 numeric , q2 numeric , q3 numeric , q4 numeric , q5 numeric , q6 numeric , q7 numeric , q8 numeric , q9 numeric , q10 numeric );
```

Be warned, you have to put together the end of the query (result type) in program. If it would be psql, then it wolud look like this:

```
SELECT format(
        $omfg$
        SELECT * FROM crosstab(
                $x$WITH a as (
                    select exid,
                        dt.id,
                        dt.code,
                        sum(value)
                    FROM datatype dt
                        JOIN model m ON m.dtid = dt.id
                    group by 1,2,3
                    order by 1,2
                ),
                b as (
                    SELECT exid
                    FROM a
                    GROUP BY 1
                )
                SELECT b.exid,
                    dt.code,
                    coalesce(a.sum, 0)
                FROM b
                    JOIN datatype dt ON true
                    LEFT JOIN a ON a.exid = b.exid
                    AND a.id = dt.id
                order by 1,2 $x$
            ) as (exid serial, %s) $omfg$,
            (
                SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(code || ' numeric'), ', ')
                FROM (
                        SELECT code
                        FROM datatype
                        order by id
                    ) c
            )
    ) \ gexec
```

Before you try to understand the code above, you should read the docs about the `crosstab` function here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/tablefunc.html (or from the docs of the appropriate PG version)

You may notice the `coalesce(a.sum,0)` instead of `a.sum` in first version. In most cases nicer to use coalesce, but in the question was some `n`-s in the table, they probably means `NULL`, without the `coalesce` you can have them (obviously).

Comment: please beautify your sql code is so it is unreadable

Comment: thank you both, changed the answer as suggested

Comment: I agree it's not straight forward, but calling it "*ridiculously hard*" is a bit exaggerated